# Shopping cart using phonegap, mobile jquery, php

Tags: cordova, jquery-mobile, phonegap

I am new in hybrid mobile app development. I want to know if I have to make a shopping cart where product variant is one of the main feature and multistore facility is there, then for which option I would go for phonegap mobile jquery or others? 
Please advice. 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

First of all, If you need to develop hybrid Mobile application, There are some available platforms like [Phonegap](https://phonegap.com/), [xamarin](https://www.xamarin.com/), [Ionic Framework](https://ionicframework.com/)

If you are talking about UI frameworks, bellow are some ..
[Framework7](https://framework7.io/)
[Jquery Mobile](https://jquerymobile.com/)

My personal suggession is, you can go through Ionic Framework, With help of it you will able to build beautiful and interactive mobile apps using HTML5 and AngularJS

Comment: Thanks for your comment, if I go for mobile jquery n phonegap would any future updation cause any issues?

Comment: Grate choice. Not any issue, Go ahead. 
I am still ok with jQuery mobile, JQM is simply awesome..   
use phonegap (with  Android Studio instead of eClipse, you might face some trouble for building application )

Comment: Can you suggest a way for page transition like slide etc. after successful login and redirect to a page where there is a list of users. I am using a function that call ajax on page load. It's working perfect if i am not using any page transition.?